# Convert multiple SFTP command lines to a single line command line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sftp

How do I convert this `EOF` into a one line `sftp` command-line?

```
sftp -v bheng@45.55.88.88 <<EOF
    mkdir /home/forge/web-app/public/backup/$HOSTNAME/$DATE
    put $path/* /home/forge/web-app/public/backup/$HOSTNAME/$DATE
    bye
EOF
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprized if nothing works, (and if `sftp` clients are as variable as `ftp` clients you may find that what works on one system doesn't work on another), but I did you try `echo "mkdir ... ; put ... ; bye" | sftp ...` ? Good luck.

Comment: Why do you want to put it on a single line? What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with SFTP/`sftp`. It's just a generic shell question.

So use any method that a shell allows, for example

```
(echo command1 && echo command2 && echo command3) | sftp ...
```